# URL Segment in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my codeigniter project, i am working around the url parameter. Its almost working but there is some problem in the view page which is loading.

I have set all the configuration as per my knowledge. But I doubt there must be some issue in the .htaccess or routes.php file.

.htaccess file --

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

routes.php --

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['home'] = 'home/index';
$route['faq'] = 'home/faq';
$route['privacy-policy'] = 'home/policy';
$route['doupnow-videos'] = 'home/videos';
$route['doupnow-audios'] = 'home/audios';
$route['morevideo/(:any)'] = 'home/morevideo/$1';
$route['moreaudio'] = 'home/moreaudio';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Controller Page --

```
public function morevideo($cat)
    {
        $result['list']=$this->Home_Model->displayVideosAll($cat);
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('doupnow-video-more', $result);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Now when i navigate to "http://doupnow.com/morevideo/latest", this page getting the parameter correctly and also displaying the data based on the parameter only but the view is not getting the html and css elements like the other pages.

Kindly give me the proper direction. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your site, when you're linking to a script or stylesheet, you link it by doing:
`/js/script.js`

But you need to give the full **url** like this:
`http://doupnow.com/js/script.js`

Comment: @Riteshgupta yes, but you're now a level deeper in the **url**. So your site thinks the path is `http://doupnow.com/morevideo/js/script.js`. If you inspect your site and check the **console** you will see that.

Comment: @Riteshgupta I hope it makes sense, otherwise let me know.

Comment: ya its working after changing the url, thnx alot   :)

Comment: @Riteshgupta Happy to help!